# Struggling to get product attribute for variable product

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

I'm currently having an issue with WooCommerce that randomly a product attribute is or is not written to the database. Result is that in the order for some items I can't see the attributes. Hence, I thought about having an intermediate solution by dumping the cart into an email to ourselves as soon as the customer hits the "order now" button.
But doing so, I'm struggling to get the attributes right.

We're selling coffee for which I have 2 attributes: `coffee_bag_size` and `coffee_ground_for`. Both attributes are set for variations, but I have created 2 only variations based on `coffee_bag_size` (for 250 grammes and 500 grammes bag) with different prices whereas the `coffee_ground_for` can be any value. I just have to know what the customer chooses.

I read in another post that in case an attribute is not used in variations, one has to get it from the parent, so I did:

```
 foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) 
   {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    
    $bagsize = $product->get_attribute('pa_coffee_bag_size')  ;
      
    // For Product Variation type
    if( $product->get_variation_id() > 0 )
     {
      $parent = wc_get_product($product->get_parent_id());
      $ground =  $parent->get_attribute('pa_coffee_ground_for')  ;          
     }
    // For other Product types
    else 
     {
      $ground =  $product->get_attribute('pa_coffee_ground_for')  ;  
     }    
   }
```

Getting the `coffee_bag_size` attribute is no problem.
Getting the `coffee_ground_for` is the problem. If I get it from the product it's empty, if I get it from the parent then I get a comma-separated list of all possible values. But I only need the value that was chosen. How do I do that?

I tried a few things more .... they all give me an empty string back:

```
$ground = $product->get_meta('pa_coffee_ground_for',true);
$ground = $cart_item['variation']['pa_coffee_ground_for'];
      
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute => $attribute_term ) 
 {
  $term = get_term_by('name','pa_coffee_ground_for', $attribute);    
  $ground = $term->term;      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out slug of you attribute it may be 'pa_coffee-ground-for'

```
  $product = $cart_item['data'];
  

  if( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) )
   {
     $product = wc_get_product($product->get_parent_id());          
   }
   $ground = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_coffee-ground-for' );
```

Tested and working